# xml and percent symbols

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm using `XMLStreamReader` to parse a piece of xml:

```
XMLStreamReader rd = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(io_xml, "UTF-8");

...

if (eventType == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
  String name = rd.getLocalName();
  if (name.equals("key")) {
    String val = rd.getElementText();
  }
}
```

Problem is, I'm getting a bad read for the following string: `"<key>cami%C3%B5es%2Babc</key>"`

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
expected:<cami[%C3%B5es%]2Babc> but was:<cami[ C3 B5es ]2Babc>
```

Do I neeed to do anything special within the XML? I already tried to put everything within a `CDATA` section but I get the same error.

---

Using a "regular" parser everything works:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document parse = builder.parse(is);
String value = parse.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was in a different section of the code. A `setter` that didn't just `set`.